# Files on my secondary hard disk keep disappearing and can be recovered with CHKDSK /F, but CHKDSK /R and SMART find nothing wrong

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, chkdsk, filesystem-corruption

My desktop has an SSD (840 Evo) as my boot drive and a 3TB WD Red as my data storage drive. I recently reinstalled Windows 10 on my desktop because it was becoming pretty bloated, and since then I've been getting issues with folders frequently disappearing off of the secondary drive.

I'm using directory junctions to move my user folders like Documents, Downloads off of my SSD onto the HDD because I don't have much space on my SSD. From what I can tell I've only had folders disappear from the directory where I keep all of my migrated 'user folders'.

- Wasn't an issue until I reinstalled windows 10
- The folder contents can be recovered using CHKDSK /F to found.000, found.001
- Happens daily, but generally only after using the computer and writing to the directories
- SMART reports no bad sectors, CHKDSK /R gave it a clean bill of health
- The SSD is not having any issues with file corruptions, nor is another SSD I've been using in the system to hold things like VM's where disk performance is a bottleneck.

Does anyone have any ideas? This is getting irritating and I'm wondering if it indicates impending drive failure or some other hardware problem.
I've got a backup of the most important files and folders off the disk.

A pastebin of the most recent output of CHKDSK /F can be found here: http://pastebin.com/Xk2wPjvc

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you run a SMART tool on your HDD?

Comment: I downloaded WD's disk utility and it reports no issues for S.M.A.R.T. I also ran a quick scan with it and it found nothing wrong.

Comment: Hmmm.. well I think a solution is new hard drive! Although that will "solve" the issue it won't help you to understand it :(

Answer (score 0):

I found that many times Fakelinks tend to have this type of behavior. No fix currently exists that will guarantee correct functionality.

Instead of using them, you should use Windows System Preparation Tool (Sysprep) in Audit Mode to correctly relocate user folders to the other drive.

There are complete guides on how to do this during installation or after windows is installed [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1964-users-folder-move-location-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I don't know if it's the directory junctions that are messing up, because they're not disappearing. They break because the 'real' folder on the other end is being corrupted. Regardless, I'll give moving my user folder a try.

Comment: They act similar to mapped drives in the sense that they can lose the link with the actual folder. The situations when this happens are various. Just to make sure the drive itself is fine, get HDTune and give it a full read test.